# sed scripts vs only using sed linux

Tags: linux, sed

if I make a sed script to edit some_file.txt, such as

```
d
s/a/b
```

would it print nothing or would it print all the lines in the file where "a" is substituted with "b" like having two separate 'sed' commands?

Comment: there's a typo in second command, should be `s/a/b/` ... and it would print nothing because all lines get deleted with `d` command preceding the `s` command... not sure what you are trying to do.. a sample input and expected output would help to understand better

Comment: If you provide more information in detail you will get more accurate answers.

Comment: It would print nothing. The `d` command deletes the pattern space and immediately starts next cycle without printing the current pattern space.